# Eclipse Initializing Quick Diff Error

Tags: eclipse, initialization, diff, startup

I am using Eclipse version 3.5.2

When I am trying to open Eclipse, an error is occuring at start and it says:

"an internal error occured during: "Initializing Quick Diff".

When I changed workspace it is working but when I try to open eclipse with default workspace in which my codes exist it is giving error again.

How can I handle it ?

1-I unbinded CTRL+3 key. (you can see details log below)
2-I unchecked quick diff enable from preferences

here is the detailed log:

```
!SESSION 2015-08-19 16:23:54.864 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2015-08-19 16:24:05.490
!MESSAGE NLS missing message: JESInputDialog_DialogTitle in: com.gt.decent.zos.uiresources

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-08-19 16:24:05.553
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'com.metrixware.cobos' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'cobos.menu/cobos.menu.cvs' is invalid): com.metrixware.cobos.actions.UnlockAction

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-08-19 16:24:05.568
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'com.metrixware.cobos' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'cobos.menu/cobos.menu.cvs' is invalid): com.metrixware.cobos.actions.LockAction

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-08-19 16:24:05.568
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'com.metrixware.cobos' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'cobos.menu/cobos.menu.cvs' is invalid): com.metrixware.cobos.actions.IsLockedAction

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2015-08-19 16:24:05.725
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2015-08-19 16:24:05.725
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+3:
Binding(CTRL+3,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.window.quickAccess,Quick Access,
        Quickly access UI elements,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.window,Window,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.quickaccess.QuickAccessHandler@612c2b,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+3,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(Model_View_Project.openMessage,Open Buildtool,
        Opens CA Gen Buildtool,
        Category(Model_View_Project.category,Mail,null,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uncheck "Java>Work in Progress>Always show Quick 
Diff coloring". and "Workbench>Editors>Text Editor"